# How to convert epoch time of one timezone to epoch time of another timezone in java?

Tags: java, timezone

I am given epoch time for GMT timezone, i need to convert this time to other timezones based on user time zone provided.

ex- time in GMT = 1551700619
    time converted to IST = 1551680819

please help me regarding this.

Comment: Do you know and have tried `java.time.ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: “Epoch” means since Jan. 1 1970 00:00 GMT.  The epoch value has a different meaning in different timezones, but the number itself should not change.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- "Epoch time" is a misnomer, and should be abolished from our vocabulary (IMHO).  [More on this here](https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/).  What you have is correctly called a "Unix Timestamp".
- Timestamps of this form are defined as seconds since the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) without accounting for leap seconds.
- Because they are based on UTC, they are *always* in terms of UTC. Presenting one as being in a different time zone is invalid, and can lead to further confusion and corruption as that timestamp is passed around.
- The timestamps `1551700619` and `1551680819` are two different points in time, separated by 5 hours and 30 minutes of elapsed time.  In other words, if there were events at these two timestamps, and you were in India and on the phone with someone in the United Kingdom, you would both experience the first event, then have to wait 5 hours and 30 minutes, then would both experience the second event.

  ```
  1551700619 == 2019-03-04T11:56:59Z == 2019-03-04T17:26:59+05:30
  1551680819 == 2019-03-04T06:26:59Z == 2019-03-04T11:56:59+05:30
  ```

Comment: Agreed.  As in the comment on the question, the number should be the same irrespective of the timezone.  Instead, displaying the time in a given timezone is a java method call.  BTW, I find "Epoch Time" to be a valid phrase and the article "Please don't call it Epoch Time" to not be withstanding.

Comment: Adjunct nouns occur in English all the time.  "chicken soup", "horse race", "milk chocolate", "shoe shop", "coffee can", "soap dish".  So "Epoch Time" is legit as the time referencing the Unix Epoch.

Comment: @MarlinPierce - So when Excel uses an Ole Automation Date (aka "OADate") which is a numeric timestamp based on a `1899-12-30` epoch, is that also "Epoch Time"?   In other words, with all of the various [epoch dates used in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), why would timestamps based on the Unix Epoch be the only one with the special distinction of being called Epoch Time?

Comment: Sure, that would be an Epoch Time too.  Are you suggesting the correct phrase is "UNIX epoch time"?

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable.